# Is there a way to directly trigger an ECS Task (i.e. without Lambda) on object upload to S3 using the Serverless Framework?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, serverless-framework

**Problem**: Trigger an ECS Task on object upload to S3. This [AWS tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-tutorial-ECS.html) makes it seem like it is possible, however there does not seem to be much information about how to do emulate this using the Serverless Framework.

**Constraint**: As explained in this [AWS tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-tutorial-ECS.html), trigger the ECS task without using an intermediary Lambda

**Disclaimer**: I am very new to serverless (both the technology and this framework) so I may be misunderstanding something fundamentally. Nevertheless, I am super eager to learn and build with these incredible tools and would appreciate any help/guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem statement is contradictory - do you want to trigger an ECS task using Lambda + Serverless, or without using Lambda? Serverless is a framework to build and deploy Lambda functions on AWS, or serverless functions on any number of IAAS providers. If you don't want a Lambda solution, you needn't use Serverless.

**Option 1 - Trigger an ECS Task from EventBridge**

This is the option detailed in the tutorial you've linked. EventBridge is an AWS service that connects various AWS, third-party or custom events to a number of supported targets.

- There already exists an event published to the default event bus on EventBridge when an object is uploaded to S3.
- Setup an event rule that fires when this event triggers.
- Setup a target on this event rule that runs an ECS task whenever the event is triggered. (So whenever an object is uploaded to S3).
  S3 upload event -> event rule -> target -> run ECS task
  You can do this on the AWS console or using the API.

**Option 2 - Trigger a Lambda function**

Looks like you're not interested in this. Listing here however because you mentioned Serverless.

- Write a Lambda function that uses the AWS API to run an ECS task whenever it is invoked.
- You can develop and deploy this function using Serverless.
- You have a couple of options on how to invoke this Lambda function

  1. Create an SNS topic and publish to this topic whenever an object is uploaded to S3. You can set this up on your S3 bucket. Hook your Lambda function to this SNS topic.
  2. Use the aforementioned AWS event and set the Lambda function as your target. A sample using Serverless is [here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/event-bridge/)